# jquery ajax how to trat callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, callback

I'm trying to use jQuery and ajax function in order to not reload the page.

So I have a basic form and I sent datas to the php file here I have no problem.

The trouble I have is to treat the return, because it return to me always success even if query failed.

in php file I have that

```
<?php

//Instantiation de la connexion
require_once('../../config/connexion.php');
//Initialisation des fichiers requis
include_once('../../lib_php/librairie.php');


//Initialisation des variables
function RecordObjectif(){
    //On cherche l'id de l'utilisateur
    $id_student = fetchUserId();
    if(isset($_POST['objectif'])){
        $objectif = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['objectif']);
        $query = "INSERT INTO ...";
        mysql_query($query);
        if(mysql_affected_rows()>=0){
            $out['erreur'] = 1;
        }else{
            $out['erreur'] = 0;
        }
        echo $out;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

echo RecordObjectif();
```

in jquery I mean Html page I have this

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'pages_ajax/mes-objectifs.php',
                    data: { objectif: objectif,  nom_programme: nom_programme, date_depart : date_depart, date_fin: date_fin, statut:statut},
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend:function(){
                        // this is where we append a loading image
                        $('#resultat').empty()
                        $('#resultat').attr('style','text-align:center');
                        $('#resultat').append('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
                    },
                     success:function(data){
                    // successful request; do something with the data
                    if(data.erreur==1){
                        $('#resultat').empty().removeAttr('style');
                        $('#resultat').attr('class','success').empty().append('<b>Enregistrement de votre programme terminé.</b>')
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    if(data.erreur==0){
                        // failed request; give feedback to user
                        $('#resultat').empty().removeAttr('style');
                        $('#resultat').attr('class','error').empty().append('<b>Erreur lors de l\'enregistrement, veuillez recommencer dans quelques minutes.</b>');
                        }
}
```

I do not know how to treat the return, It always return to me success.

I would like to display error `if $out['erreur'] = 0` what I do not understand is that I'm having always success return.

The result is not interpreted and I have still the loading icon.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should write your code in English instead of your native language. `mysql_query` is deprecated, you should use PDO instead. By the way to treat `data` in that way you should make PHP return a JSON array.

Comment: the `success` function in your jQuery ajax method doesn't care what the value of the response is, only that there is one. So if your php returns a '1' or a '0' its still a successful ajax request.

Comment: I added this `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');` into php file byt it is not enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the below block of code from  `error:function(){`

```
if(data.erreur==0){
    // failed request; give feedback to user
    $('#resultat').empty().removeAttr('style');
    $('#resultat').attr('class','error').empty().append('<b>Erreur lors de l\'enregistrement, veuillez recommencer dans quelques minutes.</b>');
}
```

and put this in `success:function(data){` as shown below :

```
success:function(data){
    // successful request; do something with the data
    if(data.erreur==1){
        $('#resultat').empty().removeAttr('style');
        $('#resultat').attr('class','success').empty().append('<b>Enregistrement de votre programme terminé.</b>')
    }
    // if faliure
    else if(data.erreur==0){
        // failed request; give feedback to user
        $('#resultat').empty().removeAttr('style');
        $('#resultat').attr('class','error').empty().append('<b>Erreur lors de l\'enregistrement, veuillez recommencer dans quelques minutes.</b>');
    }
}
```

This should do the work !

Answer (score 1):

You can not access PHP variables in the callback of an ajax request with a selector ".". But you can access the data echo'ed by the script like this:

```
.success(function(data) {
    if(data.response == 1) {
        alert('okay');
    }
});
```

The next thing is, that the error callback will be called if you return an http error code (else than 200 OK). And you always return a "200 OK" as long as your script runs without a serverside error. So the error function you define will therefore never be called. My solution for you is the following one:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'pages_ajax/mes-objectifs.php',
    data: { objectif: objectif,  nom_programme: nom_programme, date_depart : date_depart, date_fin: date_fin, statut:statut},
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend:function(){
        // this is where we append a loading image
        $('#resultat').empty()
        $('#resultat').attr('style','text-align:center');
        $('#resultat').append('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
   },
   always:function(data){
         $('#resultat').empty().removeAttr('style');

        if(data.response==1){
               // successful request; do something with the data
               $('#resultat').attr('class','success').empty().append('<b>Enregistrement de votre programme terminé.</b>')
        } else {
               // failed request; give feedback to user
               $('#resultat').attr('class','error').empty().append('<b>Erreur lors de l\'enregistrement, veuillez recommencer dans quelques minutes.</b>');
        }
   }
   });
```

And alter the line of your php script from

```
echo $out;
```

to

```
echo $out['erreur'];
```

You could also do a json_encode() on the array and return the json data of the php array, but this is an overhead in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are quite a few things in your code on which you'll need to take a look:

- You're echoing the result of the `RecordObjectif` function. That's perfectly fine, but then in the function itsself you should `return` the values instead of just echoing it.
- The `$.ajax` success function is called when the ajax request itsself was successfull, and doesn't depend on what you're php function is outputting
- To access the data you return from php, you've got `jsonencode` the php output, and use `JSON.parse` in javascript again

Just giving you some working code for this very problem won't help you, as, as far as I can see, you're lacking some basic understanding of how ajax requests work. My advice is to search some easy examples for ajax requests, and try to **really** understand what which part of the code is doing.